# Twitter library for metro app (still maintained)

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm looking for a Twitter library to use Twitter API in a metro app ... and I am hitting a wall.

So far, here is what I found :

- **Twitterizer** : Project closed, no version for metro apps
- **TweetSharp** : Project closed, no version for metro apps
- **TwitterRT** : Working for Metro app, I'm currently using it in my application, but not maintained anylonger, and not working for Twitter API 1.1 so I get 401 errors since Twitter API 1.0 is closed
- **Linq2Twitter** : It seems to be easier to create a new library from scratch than to use this one.

If any one knows a good existing library, or a clear tutorial to use Linq2Twitter (the one I find are not clear about how to connect with Oauth), I would be very glad.

*PS : If it helps, the purpose of my application is to post a status on behalf of a user.*

Comment: TwitterRT is simpler. You can update to use v1.1 API.

Comment: How do you update it to 1.1 ? The actual version uses the API 1.0 and when I change the source code to call 1.1 URLs, I still get 401 errors. I guess it's a problem with OAuth, but I'm not sure about it (It worked well when Twitter was still maintaing API 1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using Twitter RT and editing the source code to work with API 1.1

First I needed to change the *updateStatusUrl* constant :

```cs
const string _updateStatusUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
```

Then, in the PostData method, I had to explicitly specify the request mime type :

```
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

This worked for me.
I hope it will help people with the same problem.